# Why is $\ln(\sqrt{|2x-5|}) + \frac{1}{2} \ln(|2x+3|) \neq \ln(\sqrt{|2x-5|}) + \ln(\sqrt{|2x+3|})$ in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, wolfram-alpha

According to Wolfram Alpha, $$\frac{1}{2} \ln(|2x+3|) = \ln(\sqrt{|2x+3|})$$

is always true, which makes sense given what I know of log rules.

However, if I add the expression $\ln(\sqrt{|2x-5|})$ to ***both*** sides of that equation, as such: $$\ln(\sqrt{|2x-5|}) + \frac{1}{2} \ln(|2x+3|) = \ln(\sqrt{|2x-5|}) + \ln(\sqrt{|2x+3|})$$

WA tells me that the two sides of this equation are ***not always*** equal! How is this possible if $\frac{1}{2} \ln(|2x+3|) = \ln(\sqrt{|2x+3|})$ is always true and I'm adding the same expression to both sides of the equation? 
What's going on here?

**EDIT**: Here's the WA output: [image]

Comment: Error in input to WA?

Comment: @GEdgar, i don't think so unless I'm going crazy (definitely possible), I edited my OP to post the output from Wolfram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I tried it.  Now what?  Is this different from yours?

[image: WA image]

Comment: Can you try asking "Is it true that..." and then the equation? If I take that sentence out and just leave the equation, I get the same as you ("True"). However if I add "Is it true that....", then it tells me "(expression A) is not always equal to (expression B)".
If you look at my edit, don't we have the same equation? Still it tells me "...is not always equal to..."